# Rails + Bootstrap 3: Have two columns in a row, but have them collapse one column after another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is an odd problem I'm having. I have a list of names, split up into two arrays at the middle. So names A-M are in `name1` and names N-Z are in `name2`. Now I'm going through each array and putting them in a row with two columns so the names look like this:

```
Aaron    Neil
Arthur   Nick
```

etc. But when I collapse the page down, it looks like:

```
Aaron
Neil
Arthur
Nick
```

and I want it to look like:

```
Aaron
Arthur
Neil
Nick
```

Here's the haml:

```
- a = true
- index = 0
- while(a)
  - first = name1[index]
  - second = name2[index]
  - if first != nil || second != nil
    .row
      .col-md-6
        - if first
          = first
      .col-md-6
        - if second
          = second
    - index += 1
  - else
    - a = false
```

I understand why this is happening, but I'm not exactly sure how else to approach this. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new row and column for each set of names.

instead you should run your loop inside the columns like this:

```
- name1 = %w[Aaron Arthur]
- name2 = %w[Neil Nick]

.row
  .col-md-6
    -name1.each do |x|
      %p= x
  .col-md-6
    -name2.each do |x|
      %p= x
```